# Page source not showing data fetched from api in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from API using getServerSideProps with React Query. Everything is working fine but when I see the page source it's showing "Loading..." only which is not good for SEO. and yes I am not using useEffect Hook here. kindly help me out with the following code. Pagination is working fine here. the only problem is not able to the original data is not showing on the page source...
[image]

```
import axios from "axios";
import Header from '/includes/header';
import Footer from '/includes/footer';
import Breadcrumbs from '/includes/breadcrumbs';
import SnippetsPaginate from "/template/snippetswithpaginate";
import { useQuery,usePaginatedQuery } from "react-query";
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { BsChevronLeft, BsChevronRight } from "react-icons/bs";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  // Fetch the first page as default
const page = query.page || 1;
  //let snippetsData = null;
const snippetsData = await getData(page);
return { props: { snippetsData,page }}
}


 //async function getData(pageNumber) {
 const getData = async (pageNumber)=>{
var config = {
headers: { 
  accept: '*/*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'API_ACCESS_KEY': 'hns2V0Ddbkkn8r1XLq3Kw7ZoiBTR0nmA',
 }
};

const url = `http://localhost:8000/api/snippets?page=${pageNumber}`;
// const url = `${process.env.FETCH_URL}/snippets?page=${pageNumber}`;
const snippetData = await axios.get(url, config);
return snippetData.data;
}

const Snippets = ({ snippetsData,page }) => {
const  [pageNumber,setMainPage] = useState(page);
const {isLoading,
isError,
error,
data,
isFetching,
isPreviousData} = useQuery(['paginate',pageNumber],() => getData(pageNumber),{ 
 keepPreviousData : true });
 const router = useRouter();
const handlePagination = page => {
    console.log("pge",page)
    const path = router.pathname;
    const query = router.query;
    query.page = page.selected + 1;
    setMainPage(page.selected + 1);
    router.push({
        pathname: path,
        query: query,
    });
   
 }

 return (
  <>
  <Header />
  <Breadcrumbs />
  <div>
  {isLoading ? (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  ) : isError ? (
    <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
  ) : (

      
    <div>
      {data.snippets.data.map(project => (
        <p key={project.id}>{project.name}</p>
      ))}

      <ReactPaginate
          marginPagesDisplayed={2}
          pageRangeDisplayed={5}
          previousLabel={<BsChevronLeft />}
          nextLabel={<BsChevronRight />}
          breakLabel={"..."}
          initialPage={data.snippets.current_page - 1}
          pageCount={data.snippets.last_page}
          onPageChange={handlePagination}
          containerClassName={"paginate-wrap"}
          subContainerClassName={"paginate-inner"}
          pageClassName={"paginate-li"}
          pageLinkClassName={"paginate-a"}
          activeClassName={"paginate-active"}
          nextLinkClassName={"paginate-next-a"}
          previousLinkClassName={"paginate-prev-a"}
          breakLinkClassName={"paginate-break-a"}
          />


    </div>
  )}
  
  
  </div>
  </>
  );





}




export default Snippets;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the react query with the following code

```
const {isLoading,
isError,
error,
data,
isFetching,
isPreviousData} = useQuery(['paginate',pageNumber],() => getData(pageNumber),{ 
keepPreviousData : true });
```

to

```
 const {isLoading,
 isError,
 error,
 data} = useQuery(['paginate',pageNumber],() => getData(pageNumber), 
{initialData:snippetsData},{ keepPreviousData : true });
```